# Mini-PCIe card to read RAM of a device

Tags: memory, pcie, security

In a security assessment, the following statements were given:

> Threat: Spoof a device and modify RAM to add program code and change data.
>
> Skill: Simple training of a unskilled person

Since an unskilled person can perform the attack, I assume that the device to perform the attack is available on the market. So that's what I'm looking for:

- Mini PCIe-Card
- allowing to copy 512 MB RAM of the host device
- transfer the data out of the device in any kind (e.g. wireless or by storing on a SD card and then removing the Mini PCIe card again)
- cost < 500 €

Note: I'm not looking to cause a security breach, but rather the opposite: understanding the attack and performing security tests for my devices.

Comment: You're probably thinking of a [DMA attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMA_attack) - the classic vector is firewire.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek: yes, except that my device doesn't have Firewire.